# Using readline(prompt = "") in rMarkdown

Tags: r, markdown, readline

I'm currently attempting to automate some statistical report generation, however to do so I would like to collect a couple of piece of information from the user before beginning, then create a markdown report from it.

When knitting the document however it hangs forever because it has no route to receive the user input from. Does anyone know of one, or would it be a case of using a separate r script to gather the information then using calling the report generation from within that using `rmarkdown::render`?

Answer (score 2):

You could embed a [Shiny app](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html) or make use of [parameterized reports](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html) in the Rmarkdown document. Without further detail (eg some code), it is hard to tell you more.

I hope that this helps, though.